# PHP mySQL fetch data if no match in second table

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is supposed to return results that either match a parameter in another table or don't match the ID at all.

This is my attempt and I don't understand why it does not work. It returns many times the number of results.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table2, table1
  WHERE table1.ID = table2.name 
        AND table1.value = 1 
        OR table1.ID != table2.name
```

How can this be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some parenthesis

```
FROM table2, table1 WHERE (table1.ID = table2.name AND table1.value = 1) OR table1.ID != table2.name

FROM table2, table1 WHERE table1.ID = table2.name AND (table1.value = 1 OR table1.ID != table2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

- A left outer join (or right)
- Or a full outer join

Look to here for an explanation of them: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-full-outer-join.php

```
SELECT *
  FROM table2, table1
  WHERE table1.ID = table2.name(+) 
        AND table1.value = 1
```

An example up, there, untested but I think it'll work